# MSVC2013 and new array brace-initialization issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've been looking at this small snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char const *a = "my string";
    size_t len = strlen(a);
    char *b = new char[len + 1]{0};

    char *zeroes = new char[strlen(a) + 1];
    memset(zeroes, 0, strlen(a) + 1);

    std::cout << memcmp(b, zeroes, strlen(a) + 1); // 0 expected
}
```

[gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e6f9aa2c49d4707) and [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bee8165f66949d8a) correctly output `0` but MSVC2013 Update 3 outputs `1`.

I read `5.3.4/17` regarding `new` and *new-initializer* but couldn't find anything justifying MSVC's behavior.

Am I missing something? Is this a known issue?

---

Edit: I'm attaching the memory dump from MSVC and the generated assembly code (*x64 release*)

[image]

```
int main()
{
000007F676571270  push        rbx  
000007F676571272  sub         rsp,20h  
    char const *a = "my string";
    size_t len = strlen(a);
    char *b = new char[len + 1]{0};
000007F676571276  mov         ecx,0Ah  
000007F67657127B  call        operator new[] (07F676571704h)  
000007F676571280  mov         rbx,rax  
000007F676571283  test        rax,rax  
000007F676571286  je          main+1Dh (07F67657128Dh)  
000007F676571288  mov         byte ptr [rax],0  // zero the first one out
000007F67657128B  jmp         main+1Fh (07F67657128Fh)  
000007F67657128D  xor         ebx,ebx  

    char *zeroes = new char[strlen(a) + 1];
000007F67657128F  mov         ecx,0Ah  
000007F676571294  call        operator new[] (07F676571704h)
```

Comment: Have you dumped the arrays in gdb etc.?

Comment: I did in MSVC, I'm attaching the memory dump

Comment: Have you tried without the `0`, i.e. `new char[len + 1]{};`? I mean it should still zero everything out with a single zero, but it'd be interesting to see.

Comment: @user657267 That works and correctly outputs 0

Comment: I think this has to be a bug, IIRC if you initialize an array with fewer elements than the size the rest are zeroed.

Comment: @user657267 That's correct, it should be around clause 5 and 8.5 in the standard

Comment: Yup from [dcl.init.aggr]/7, element 0 is initialized to 0, and elements 1-9 should all be initialized to `char{}`, i.e. 0. You can use the Feedback Tool to report a bug.

Comment: You are relying on C++14 behavior, 2013 < 14.

Comment: @HansPassant Clang and gcc do the right thing in `-std=c++11`

Comment: @HansPassant The C++11 grammar already had *brace-or-equal-initializer* syntax.

Comment: Sure, that's why new char[len + 1]{} works.

Comment: @HansPassant So why isn't `new char[len + 1]{0}` C++11? It's still just aggregate initialization right?

Comment: C++14 has a new rule when the initializer doesn't contain enough elements.  Quote: "the remaining members are initialized by their brace-or-equal initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14) by empty lists, which performs value-initialization".  I assume that this applies here.

Comment: @HansPassant I can't seem to find that quote in n3797, but aggregate initialization in n3242 (pre-c++11) is equivalent "If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug of MS VC++ compiler. According to the C++ Standard (5.3.4 New)

17 A new-expression that creates an object of type T initializes that object as follows:

— If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5); if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value.

— Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for directinitialization.

And further (8.5.1 Aggregates)

7 If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there is no brace-or-equalinitializer, from an empty initializer list (8.5.4).

and (8.5.4 List-initialization)

— Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized

and at last (8.5 Initializers)

8 To value-initialize an object of type T means

...

— if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
— otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

So all elements of the array shall be zero initialized.